# How to go to another website in an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC web application? I get CORS error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0

I am using ASP.NET Core 7 MVC. I want to go to another website after a result is true.

In the controller is declared something like this:

```
public ActionResult CalculateSomething(string encIds, string url)
{
    try
    {    
        resultIs = true;

        if (resultIs)
        {
            string newUrl = "https://www.ad.nl";

            return Redirect(newUrl);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string s = ex.Message;
        return Json(s);
    }
}
```

In the `appsettings` I have this config:

```
"AllowedCorsOrigins": "https://localhost:7065/",
```

In `program.cs`:

```
var allowedCorsOrigins = configuration.GetValue<string>("AllowedCorsOrigins");
    
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins(allowedCorsOrigins)
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
```

I get an error message like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please include `return` so that it should hit that URL.

Comment: What is `resultIs` can you please share that as well?

Comment: Since its your site that hits the `ad.nl`, it's they who should have the CORS policy, not you. Apparently they don't support CORS.

Comment: I do not ask questions to Chat. They always give wrong answers. My only wish is to go to another website. And I don't understand why it is so difficult. I try it first without that CORS shit. So I am not interested in the CORS policy. I just want a correct way to leave my site to go to another site...

Comment: resultIs is an example. Let's say resultIs = true;

Comment: Sorry I forgot the word return. But it's in my code on the right way.

Comment: How are calling `CalculateSomething`? I have tested the same way I gave you the example and working fine. Could you please share how this action method being called?

Comment: Just a button on a cshtml-page.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that the ActionResult was called in a js-file. The button calls the js-function. And via the js-function you call my acctionresult in the controller.

Changed in code in Controller:

```
if (restApi.Result.Success)
{
    return Json(new { success = restApi.Result.Success, url = restApi.Result.Redirect });

}

return Json(new { success = restApi.Result.Success, data = restApi.Result.ErrorMsg });
```

In js

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + `/MeWebsite/CalculateSomething?encIds=${encIds}&url=${curUrl}`,
    //data: formdata,
    type: 'POST',
    
     success: function (result) {
        if (result.success) {
              // I added this row
              window.location = result.url;
        } else {
            console.error(result);
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.error(data);
    },
    complete: function (data) {
        HideWait();
    }
});
```

Comment: Nowhere within your question, nothing about your client side code man, how do the contributor would know about? anyway, glad to see that, you were able o resolve your issue. However, its always recommended to share the scenario with details and clear description along with the required code snippet so that it can be investigate accordingly.

Comment: In the cshtml-page there is a button with an Id. And then with $(document).on('click', '#myId", function (e) {. it's called the function where the ajax-call is coded. Everything is very dynamically. The js-file is included in _Layout... That is default programming.